# Filter by table when you have multiple unions tables in function

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel function with multiple union tables. So in my blade I can export all union tables in a single html table. 
I'm looking to add an option to filter data displayed by table. (Choose to display only data relative to a specific table). how can we do that ?

**My controller code.**

```
$table1 = Invoice::where('validate','=','1')
    ->whereBetween('updated_at', [$date1, $date2])
    ->union($table2)
    ->union($table3)
    ->union($table4)
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

**My view:**

```
@foreach($table1 as $table)
    {{$table->id}}
@endforeach
```

I want in example to show in my html table only data relative to `$table3`. Thank you

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses

Comment: Why not adjust your query so that you are only querying the tables you need instead of getting data you don't need.

Comment: @YahyaUddin sometimes i will need all  data, sometimes i will need specefic data

Comment: So the times you need specific data, use conditions to customise your query so you only get the data you need. Can you expand your question so it's clear what the conditions are.